# Getting error while Google Pay integration in android app – UPI Payment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, google-pay

I have integration Google Pay in android app – UPI Payment. Below is the sample code link.

https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments

But while pay the 10 Rs getting error as below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the app. The bank account you are using in google pay has no limit set for UPI transactions. Login to net banking for your bank account and get that sorted.

Comment: If I close the app and directly open google pay and do the transaction it's working.

Comment: you could resolve it ?